# Laravel Remember Me cookie not being set

Tags: php, cookies, laravel, laravel-4, remember-me

I recently built my first web application using laravel and overall it has been great.  I have picked up the framework very easily except for this one issue.  I am trying to use the framework's built in authentication.  I am able to log in my users for a given request but I am trying to implement the remember me functionality by the `Auth::attempt()` method passing in true as the second parameter as per the documentation.[image: Laravel Documentation]

I have been trying this method for many hours without any luck.  I have seen a video at this url (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hYUf6u_txhk#aid=P-a-d6RlOC8) which shows which cookie is set when a user is remembered in the application and this cookie is not being set in my browser when I try to remember my user. The cookie is not being set and my users are not being remembered.  Here is my code.

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => Input::get('password')), true))
        {
            $userid = DB::table('users')->where('email', '=', $userdata['email'])->pluck('id');

            Auth::login(Auth::user());

            if (Auth::check())
            {
                echo "LOGGGEED IN WOOOOOOO";
            }
            else {
                echo "user not logged in";
            }

            return Redirect::to('/dashboard/' . $userid);
        }
```

Before the redirect happens here is the page I see
[image]

Here is the controller that handles the redirect.

```
class DashboardController extends BaseController
{
public function showDashboard($userid)
{
    if (Auth::viaRemember())
    {
        echo "WOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO";

    }
    else {
        echo 'booooooo';
    }
    if (Auth::check())
    {
        echo 'YAY LOGGED IN';
    }
    else {
        echo 'BOO AGAIN';
    }
    $user = User::where('id', '=', $userid)->first();
    $subscriptions = $user->subscriptions;
    $orders = $user->orders;

    return View::make('dashboard', compact('user', 'subscriptions', 'orders'));
}
}
```

But when the redirect happens and /dashboard/{userid} is loaded you can see in the top left hand corner that my `echo` statements show the user is not being remembered!
[image]

I am so frustrated at this point since this is the last step I need to finish my application and I am embarrassed that the laravel documentation says "Laravel aims to make the implementation simple".  I have the entire rest of my application working EXCEPT for this part so I would appreciate any and all help with this issue! If you need anymore information please feel free to ask me.[Dashboard page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApRbq.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SOLUTION:

In app/config/session.php in the array my 'driver' key had a value of 'file'.  After switching this to 'cookie' everything worked as expected.

Comment: I have not seen any changes in user table's remember_token column. I have checked it using Auth::ViaRemember. But it failed. Please advice..